# sqlite3 memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, sqlite

I'm developing an app with makes an heavy use of sqlite3 and I'm facing a huge memory leaks problem.

Every time I call the method which makes the select I get memory leaks when I add the object to the array.

```
    - (void) makeSitesSelect:(NSString *)dbPath:(NSString *)theSelect {
    allSitesSelect = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql = [theSelect cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSMutableArray *selResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // <---- Memory leak
                NSInteger selprimaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                [selResult addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", selprimaryKey]]; //<--- memory leak

                const unsigned char *chsiteSite = sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1);
                const unsigned char *chsiteCity = sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2);
                const unsigned char *chsiteCountry = sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3);
                const unsigned char *chsiteGPS = sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4);

                if (chsiteSite != NULL) {
                    [selResult addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)]]; //<--- memory leak
                }
                else {
                    [selResult addObject:@""];
                }

                if (chsiteCity != NULL) {
                    [selResult addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)]]; //<---- memory leak
                }
                else {
                    [selResult addObject:@""];
                }
                if (chsiteCountry != NULL) {
                    [selResult addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)]]; //<---- memory leak
                }
                else {
                    [selResult addObject:@""];
                }
                if (chsiteGPS != NULL) {
                    [selResult addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)]]; //<---- memory leak
                }
                else {
                    [selResult addObject:@""];
                }
                [allSitesSelect addObject:selResult];
                [selResult release];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Try allocating it outside while loop....tat is b4 while-loop

Comment: quote: "I'm developing an app with makes an heavy use of sqlite3"... have you considered Core Data? You should try it, it's simple to learn and really efficient!

Comment: @booleanBoy: I can't allocate selResult outside the while loop because I have to empty e reinit it at every "lap".

Comment: daveoncode: could be nice, but I'm updating an already released app and I would add thousands of lines to move from sqlite to CoreData without problems for all users already use my app.

Comment: why is that line a memory leak?
 [selResult addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)]]; //<--- memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Is your allSitesSelect is an properties then you should always use self.allSitesSelect = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and you are responsible to release after no use. and you are not releasing database as well.

you do not need to create selResult each time in while loop

```
NSMutuableArray selResult*
while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
     if(selResult == nil){
         selResult = [NSMutuableArray copy] //Its an autorelease(you don't need
                                             //release explicitly )
     }
}
```

Comment: Even if the problem is not with allSitesSelect but with selResult, I did what you suggested (the allSitesSelect was already released in dealloc method). About releasing database, if I do a [database release] it returns me an error with sqlite3*

Comment: @masgar i have improved my answer to clear your doubt, hope so.

Answer (score 0):

You try like this

```
if (!allSitesSelect)
{
 allSitesSelect = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

and release this array in dealloc

```
[allSitesSelect release];
```